# Bootstrap 4 - align anchor with heading element in card-head

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4+ to create a card with collapsable card-body, triggered by a link in the card-head.

```
<div class="card text-left mb-3 mt-3">
  <div class="card-head p-3">
    <h4>How do we get started?</h4>
    <a class="float-right" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
    More
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The  tag showing "more" is not lining up vertically inline with the heading element next to it.

It looks like this in chrome:

[image]

How can I get the heading and "More" link (vertically) inline with each other? thereby reducing the wasted vertical height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `d-flex justify-content-between` classes with your `card-head` class will resolve your issue. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

> **Bootstrap 4 Flexbox - [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/)**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card text-left mb-3 mt-3">
  <div class="card-head p-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
    <h4>How do we get started?</h4>
    <a class="float-right" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
    More
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `d-flex align-items-center` which is available in Bootstrap 4+ in your `card-head` and also you don't need to use `float-right` instead you can use `ml-auto`. Something like this

```
<div class="card text-left mb-3 mt-3">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center card-head p-3">
    <h4>How do we get started?</h4>
    <a class="ml-auto" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">
    More
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  <div class="card card-body">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should they use `ml-auto`?

Comment: Basically flex was introduced as an alternative for floats to define the overall appearance of a web page. A float usually only allow you to horizontally position and element but with flexbox it gives you complete control over the alignment and direction of the elements which is why it is advised not to use float when you are using flex layout and the reason for using ml-auto